# Make [quirksmode] a tag synonym of [quirks-mode]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Currently these are two separate tags, but relate to the same thing (browser quirks mode). [quirks-mode](/questions/tagged/quirks-mode) would seem to be a lot more popular. Most questions tagged [quirksmode](/questions/tagged/quirksmode) are also tagged [quirks-mode](/questions/tagged/quirks-mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were sufficiently few questions with the unhyphenated tag that one could retag them manually, but I went with a merge + synonym anyway, just because.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, there were previously 163 questions tagged "quirks-mode" and 19 tagged "quirksmode". Now there are 173 tagged "quirks-mode" and 0 tagged "quirksmode" - what happened to 9 of them?

Comment: @w3d: Those 9 questions contained *both* tags, so there was no transfer; the superfluous tag was simply removed.

Comment: Ah yes, of course!